# creating a monster battle with a multisided dice class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm making a basic battle program with a multi-sided dice class and a while loop. Basically, you and a dragon start with 100 health, and a 20 sided dice is randomly thrown to determine how much damage you each do. For example, if I rolled a six, and the dragon rolled an 8, then I would have 92 health left, and the dragon would have 94 health left. And this would continue until one health value reaches 0. Here's an example of my code below:

```
import random

class MSDie:
    def __init__(self, num_sides):
        self.num_sides = num_sides
        self.current_value = self.roll()

    def roll(self):
        self.current_value = random.randrange(1,self.num_sides+1)
        return self.current_value
    
    def __int__(self):
        return int(self.current_value)
    
    def getValue(self):
        return self.value

    def setValue(self, value):
        self.value = value

    
print("you are a legendary hero on a quest to save the kingdom from an evil dragon.")
print("You find him outside his lair and the two of you begin to battle.")
print("Both you and the dragon start with 100 health.")
print("You each will both randomly deal between 1-20 damage.")
print("The first whose health drops to 0 loses.")
playerHealth = 100
DragonHealth = 100

while(playerHealth > 0 or DragonHealth > 0):
    print("You have ", playerHealth, "Health.")
    print("The dragon has ", DragonHealth, "Health.")
    myDamage = MSDie(20)
    DragonDamage = MSDie(20)
    playerHealth = playerHealth - DragonDamage
    DragonHealth = DragonHealth - myDamage
    print("")
    print("You dealt ", myDamage, "to the dragon.")
    print("The dragon dealth ", DragonDamage, "to you.")
    print("")
```

However, each time I try to subtract the damage roll from the health, I keep getting this error:

```
File "C:\Users\Jacks\OneDrive\Documents\Python files\Ds files\monsterbattle.py", line 52, in <module>
    playerHealth = playerHealth - DragonDamage

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'MSDie'
```

Answer (score 0):

`DragonDamage` is an instance of the `MSDie` class. Python won't convert it to an integer automatically, even though you implemented the `__int__` method. You need to do this explicitly. Try `playerHealth - int(DragonDamage)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

class MSDie:
    def __init__(self, num_sides):
        self.num_sides = num_sides
        self.current_value = self.roll()

    def roll(self):
        self.current_value = random.randrange(1,self.num_sides+1)
        return self.current_value
    
    def __int__(self):
        return int(self.current_value)
    
    def getValue(self):
        return self.value

    def setValue(self, value):
        self.value = value

    

print("you are a legendary hero on a quest to save the kingdom from an evil dragon.")
print("You find him outside his lair and the two of you begin to battle.")
print("Both you and the dragon start with 100 health.")
print("You each will both randomly deal between 1-20 damage.")
print("The first whose health drops to 0 loses.")
playerHealth = 100
DragonHealth = 100

while(playerHealth > 0 or DragonHealth > 0):
    print("You have ", playerHealth, "Health.")
    print("The dragon has ", DragonHealth, "Health.")
    myDamage = MSDie(20)
    DragonDamage = MSDie(20)
    playerHealth = playerHealth - int(DragonDamage)
```

As @mcsoini suggested above, you need to explicitly convert to int.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you smiplify a lot your code. You need only one `MSDie` instance, not 2 at each loop iteration, and the dice may just provide values, it doesn't need an internal value . Also you may use `and` in your condition, to stop when one reach 0

```
class MSDie:
    def __init__(self, num_sides):
        self.num_sides = num_sides

    def roll(self):
        return random.randrange(1, self.num_sides + 1)
```

Using

```
player_health = 100
dragon_health = 100
multi_dice = MSDie(20)

while player_health > 0 and dragon_health > 0:
    player_damage = multi_dice.roll()
    dragon_damage = multi_dice.roll()
    player_health -= dragon_damage
    dragon_health -= player_damage
    print("You dealt ", player_damage, "to the dragon, it now have", dragon_health)
    print("The dragon dealth ", dragon_damage, "to you, you now have", player_health)
    print("")

if player_health > dragon_health:
    print(f"You won with {player_health}PV, dragon is dead")
else:
    print(f"You loose, you're dead, dragon has {dragon_health}PV")
```